# Is there a keyboard shortcut to select text at random location and climb to the top with one click?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-code, json

As you can see, there are more than 70000 lines, it would take a lifetime to climb to the top using `SHIFT + Page Up` or `SHIFT + UP ARROW`.

[image]

Is there any shortcut to getting to the top quickly?

Comment: Usually Ctril and Home for most Apps.

Comment: Hi @John Works with ```Ctrl + Shift + Home```, if possible add an answer for me to close the question, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this article (PDF)

[Visual Studio Shortcuts](https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-windows.pdf)

Ctrl-Home (Ctrl-End) to the beginning and end of line

Ctrl - Shift - Home (- End) to the beginning and end of file.

Ctrl - Home / End can work with Integrated terminal to go to beginning and end of file. So it depends in part on how you are using Visual Studio.

This article is handy and also for customizations.

[Customizations](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings)

Answer (score 1):

The conventional shortcut for going to the beginning of a document or file is Ctrl/Home.
If that doesn't work in your app you'll have to consult its documentation.